# UIActivity Duplicate Calls to 'activityViewController'

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a `UIActivity` that implements the `activityViewController` method. Everything works fine, except when a user quickly double taps on the icon for my activity. This causes duplicate calls to the method and crashes with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .'

I am using a custom `UIActivityItemProvider` as data that makes a server call (and can be slow) and this seems to be the cause of the issue.

How can I make sure two view controllers aren't being presented?
**Note:** This is being done through the `UIActivityViewController` so I don't think I have access to any buttons to disable them.

Comment: With UIActivityViewController in iOS6, tap or doubleTaps fire same action. Why do you know it duplicate?

Comment: @UFO I know because of the crash message and because the method is getting called twice.

Comment: I've test, both tap and doubleTap work OK. Try to use presentViewController:animated:completion: instead of presentModalViewController

Comment: @UFO As stated I don't control the presentation of the view controller. I am simply implementing the `activityViewController` method on a `UIActivity`.

Answer (score -4):

disable that button after first click, and enable after dismiss that activityViewController

Comment: or check everytime if activityViewController is null and if yes - open it

Comment: `UIActivity` is presented through a `UIActivityViewController` and I don't believe I have access to the button (unless you know how to get a reference)